# .sort in protocol extension is not working

Tags: swift, sorting, swift3, swift-protocols, swift-extensions

I have a protocol as well as a protocol extension and I'd like to implement a function in the protocol extension to sort an array defined by the protocol with custom objects, but it's not working.

```
protocol MyProtocol {
    var myArray: [MyObject] { get set }
}

extension MyProtocol {
    func sortArrayByCreationTime() {
        myArray.sort {
            $0.created > $1.created
        }
    }
}
```

Xcode is telling me that 'sort' has been renamed to 'sorted(by:)', but if im using this a new array gets created, but I need the old array to be sorted, not a new one.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your code is never going to compile as it stands, because what guarantee has the compiler that an array element has a `created` property?

Comment: @matt Apparently the compiler can infer the `created` property from the `MyObject` type.

Comment: @vadian My point is that the OP should have showed MyObject as part of the question. A MCVE requires enough code to compile.

Comment: That error message is somewhat misleading. It also occurs if you try to sort an array that was declared using `let` instead of `var`. It would be better if it explained that `sort` cannot be called on an immutable array.

Answer (score 1):

It's a misleading error – the problem is that you need to mark your `sortArrayByCreationTime()` method as [`mutating`](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH25-ID271) in order to tell the compiler that it's mutating a property (as protocols can be adopted by both value and reference types):

```
extension MyProtocol {
    mutating func sortArrayByCreationTime() {
        myArray.sort {
            $0.created > $1.created
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. If I'm doing this, what else do I have to do to use this function in a class implementing the protocol, because now I'm getting this error: `Cannot use a mutating member in immutable value: 'self' is immutable`

Comment: @eLwoodianer Hard to know without seeing how you're trying to call it – I would advise posting a new question with a [mcve] of the code that's causing the error (take heed of matt's comment above – although it wasn't part of the problem in this particular question, you should always post an MCVE if you're asking a question about a problem with your code.)

Comment: @eLwoodianer I got the same error if the instance of the class implementing the protocol was created using `let`. If I created my class instance as `var`, I could call `sortArrayByCreationTime` on it.

Answer (score 0):

I created a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE) out of the original code, and I made it work in a Swift 3 playground

```
import UIKit
import XCTest

extension Date
{
    init?(year: Int, month: Int, day: Int) {
        var dateComponents = DateComponents()
        dateComponents.day = day
        dateComponents.month = month
        dateComponents.year = year
        guard let date = Calendar.current.date(from: dateComponents)
        else { return nil }
        self = date
    }
}

struct MyObject {
    var created: Date
}

protocol MyProtocol {
    var myArray: [MyObject] { get set }
}

extension MyProtocol {
    mutating func sortArrayByCreationTime() {
        myArray.sort {
            $0.created > $1.created
        }
    }
}

struct ArrayContainer: MyProtocol {
    var myArray: [MyObject]
}

let objects = [
    MyObject(created: Date(year: 2016, month: 9, day: 1)!),
    MyObject(created: Date(year: 2016, month: 11, day: 1)!),
    MyObject(created: Date(year: 2016, month: 4, day: 1)!),
    MyObject(created: Date(year: 2016, month: 8, day: 1)!),
]
var container = ArrayContainer(myArray: objects)

var dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMdd"

XCTAssertEqual(["0901", "1101", "0401", "0801"],
               container.myArray.map { dateFormatter.string(from: $0.created) })
container.sortArrayByCreationTime()
XCTAssertEqual(["1101", "0901", "0801", "0401"],
               container.myArray.map { dateFormatter.string(from: $0.created) })
```

Let me give two options:

## Option 1: Improved

In Option 1, extend the Array struct, so that you can create mutating method `sortByCreationDate`. There is a trick that needs to be pulled out of a hat in order to extend [MyObject] (an array of MyObject)

```
protocol MyObjectProtocol { var created: Date { get set } }
extension MyObject: MyObjectProtocol { }
extension Array where Element: MyObjectProtocol {
    mutating func sortByCreationTime() {
        self.sort {
            $0.created > $1.created
        }
    }
}

var container2 = ArrayContainer(myArray: objects)
XCTAssertEqual(["0901", "1101", "0401", "0801"],
               container2.myArray.map { dateFormatter.string(from: $0.created) })
container2.myArray.sortByCreationTime()
XCTAssertEqual(["1101", "0901", "0801", "0401"],
               container2.myArray.map { dateFormatter.string(from: $0.created) })
```

## Option 2: Better

In Option 2, extend Sequence. A sequence will allow you to sort objects that are Arrays, and other types, e.g., Dictionaries. Better yet, it does not create a mutating method. But honestly `MyProtocol` is a confusing API. With this method, `MyProtocol` is no longer necessary.

```
extension Sequence where Iterator.Element == MyObject {
    func sortedByCreationTime() -> [Iterator.Element] {
        return self.sorted {
            $0.created > $1.created
        }
    }
}
var container3 = ArrayContainer(myArray: objects)
XCTAssertEqual(["0901", "1101", "0401", "0801"],
               container3.myArray.map { dateFormatter.string(from: $0.created) })
XCTAssertEqual(["1101", "0901", "0801", "0401"],
               container3.myArray.sortedByCreationTime().map { dateFormatter.string(from: $0.created) })
```