# 'Incorrect argument label' when method overloading in Swift

Tags: swift, parameters, overloading

I am trying to do method overloading in Swift with the following code:

```
struct Game {
    private let players: [UserProfile] //set in init()
    private var scores: [Int] = []

    mutating func setScore(_ score: Int, playerIndex: Int) {

        //... stuff happening ...

        self.scores[playerIndex] = score
    }

    func setScore(_ score: Int, player: UserProfile) {
        guard let playerIndex = self.players.index(of: player) else {
            return
        }

        self.setScore(score, playerIndex: playerIndex)
    }
}
```

I am getting an error on the `self.setScore` line:

`Incorrect argument labels in call (have _:playerIndex:, expected _:player:)`

I have been looking at this code for a while now but can't figure out why this wouldn't work. Any hints?

Comment: You're trying to call a `mutating` method inside a non-`mutating` method – similar Q&A: http://stackoverflow.com/q/40811214/2976878

Comment: you are right! thank you. if you make an answer out of it I will accept.

Comment: Cases like this where the error message is a red herring should be [filed as compiler bugs to the Swift open source project](http://bugs.swift.org).

Comment: Please write your solution up as a proper answer, and accept it so that this question can be considered resolved

Comment: @BlackWolf Feel free to move your edit to the question into an self-answer (for that is where it belongs) – personally, I think it's close enough to http://stackoverflow.com/q/40811214/2976878 to be a dupe (although annoyingly cannot close as dupe as neither answer is accepted or upvoted).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Hamish for pointing me in the right direction.

Turns out that the compiler message is rather misleading. The problem is that every method that calls a `mutating` method must be `mutating` itself. So this solves the problem:

```
struct Game {
    private let players: [UserProfile] //set in init()
    private var scores: [Int] = []

    mutating func setScore(_ score: Int, playerIndex: Int) {

        //... stuff happening ...

        self.scores[playerIndex] = score
    }

    mutating func setScore(_ score: Int, player: UserProfile) {
        guard let playerIndex = self.players.index(of: player) else {
            return
        }

        self.setScore(score, playerIndex: playerIndex)
    }
}
```

Also see [.sort in protocol extension is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40811214/sort-in-protocol-extension-is-not-working)

Comment: Wow this is really a confusing compiler error. Thanks!